# Wordpress get from single.php back to the right category page

Tags: categories

in my **single.php** i have a link back to the category:

`$category_id = get_the_category(); 
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id[0]->cat_ID );`

If i am now coming from **page 2** to the single, is there a way to go directly back to the second page?

---

Edit

is there a better way than using the js `history.back()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
<?php
if ( ! empty ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) )
{
?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ) ?>">Go Back</a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: And to expand on that, you could do an if statement to change which version of the link shows:

if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
referer link
} else {
normal link
}